Thoughts on adding a Close reason: Rule of Cool
I have opined in many places that sometimes the best World Building strategy is to simple declare that something IS or IS NOT and then leave it at that.
It is often an element that many world builders struggle with.
There are times when having a fully thought out world down to every nut, bolt and little detail is good.
And there are times when to do that would break the suspension of disbelief and actually run counter to the act of World Building.
Perhaps the best example would be the Force in the original Star Wars trilogy:

For my ally is the Force, and a powerful ally it is. Life creates it, makes it grow. Its energy surrounds us and binds us. Luminous beings are we, not this crude matter.

It allows Yoda and Luke and Darth Vader to do all manner of magical things.
Did anyone who watched the original trilogy stop to ask how it all worked - No! Because they didnt need to
Then, along comes the prequal Trilogy and we have Midiclorians and other stuff that IMO ruined part of the World Building established in the original.
In short - sometimes, we should close a question because to answer it would be detrimental to the Querants world building or story
And to this end, I propose the following site-specific Closure reason:

Rule of Cool
This question proposes an idea or concept that would not benefit from further
explanation.

With an expanded Wiki entry that talks about the above need for restraing in World Building.
Edit
This question, based on JBHs feedback has been superceeded - here - where it is proposed that Rule of Cool be a valid non-answer, in the tradition of Frame Challenges.

You’re correct that we should discourage this but it’s not something we can decide based on the question alone. The specifics of their writing dictate what details of their world are or are not necessary. Imagine Andy Weir’s books but with 40k style technobabble, or attempting to provide Weir’s level of grounded in real world physics to any the iconic aspects of the grim dark 41st millennium. If you’re not a Weir or Stephenson you probably don’t need those details anyway.

I'd VTC too... except that I don't have a vote so much as a sledge-hammer...

@MontyWild - I VTC'd this too, as its now surplus to requirement.

I've seen a sufficient number of questions over the years where I thought the OP was chasing the rabbit too far to dismiss this question out of hand. One of the reasons questions are closed is to give the OP time to improve the question before a boat load of lousy or misdirected answers start appearing. But there are pros and cons to all things, so let's see where this takes us.
1. Rule of Cool close reason
Pros:

Forces the OP to justify why they need more detail. This is as much a benefit to the OP as it is to the community and helping the community understand why a question has been asked would have improved many a question. I can't tell you how many times I thought a question needed such an explanation and left a comment asking for it, but I can tell you the number of times an OP complied and provided it: once.

Stops a plethora of (likely) low quality answers to an idea that's deemed capable of standing on its own.

Probably the only positive close reason we'd have (you're idea is so good that we're not willing to host answers unless you can explain why the jewel should be damaged...).

Requires a consensus of users to invoke. Unless you're a moderator - but they're pretty good about wielding the Mjölnir of votes so I'm not worried about that.


Cons:

Closed questions will always be perceived as a negative.

probably too subjective even with a page or two of explanation somewhere.

The querent may become frustrated with the action, which would rationalize the first bullet under "pros" in spades, but the action the OP may take is to abandon the question thinking there's no hope of it ever being answered. (Personally, I think I'm stretching with this one.)


2. Rule of Cool Challenge
Don't get me wrong, I like the idea of this close reason and I've upvoted Demon's proposal. But if the community isn't willing to take this step, then let's propose an alternative to test the proverbial waters. We already have one answer exception: the frame challenge. A frame challenge is a non-answer answer that explains a potential problem the OP might have overlooked.
This would be a second approved answer exception: a non-answer that explains why the idea is good enough to not require the answer the OP wants.
Why is it important to define answer exceptions in meta policy? Because it's how we avert deleting answers that don't answer the presented question but are still useful.
Pros:

Lets community members worried about the consequences of close reasons breathe while we collect more data.

Doesn't have the negative stigma of a closed question.

Provides a specific explanation for why a specific question doesn't need the requested answer (compared to the close process where only a general explanation would be provided).


Cons:

Doesn't require multiple users to invoke the process. Said another way, there's no gate stopping a Rule of Cool Challenge answer from appearing (unlike the close reason where a consensus must be formed before it happens).

Doesn't force the OP to improve anything. IMO, most querents wouldn't learn much from Rule of Cool Challenges. It takes a mature person to look past an immediate want or need to see a bigger picture. But, the same could be said of frame challenges.


So, I'm advocating for the close reason. But if the community wants to take baby steps, then we need a Meta post similar to the frame challenge post I linked to earlier that clearly explains the "Rule of Cool Challenge" including expectations for what such an answer must contain (such as worldbuidling process notes), when it can be used, and why.

I feel this is a good compromise, I will sit on this a few days and see what others think, then I may add to the question or ask a new one. Or something.

Of course, in reading your response, I find it very compelling in spite of my own reservations.

I have marked this as the answer - and created a new Meta Post - I think Rule of Cool as an acceptable non-Answer, in the same vein as a Frame Challenge is the way forward. It allows for us to provide feedback and not answer the question, without the stigma and hassle of adding it as a close reason - thanks for the input.

I Feel Your Pain

So, I certainly see where you're coming from, and I get why you would propose this. This is because I agree with you that there are times when there's too much of a muchness; and there are times when, perhaps, we might warn a fellow worldbuilder, author or game designer that what you've got is good and perfect is the enemy of good.

Fair enough for engineering!

But to be fair... I think many of us actually did (and do) ask exactly that question! How does the Force work? I agree, as a matter of writing the tale, such questions do not need to be addressed within the story. Likewise, we never learn how Gandalf or Galdriel's "magic" works. (Though, knowing JRRT, one can make a very educated guess!) Nor do we learn how magic works in the wizarding world. Yet, these are valid rabbit holes for the worldbuilder to jump into.

Me, I wasn't that put out by the explanation of midichlorians. I see that as a possibility that could be deepened and explored in more detail: who are the midichlorians; what is their purpose; what is their design and policy in the world? In other words, we can delve into a whole new dimension of the SW universe. For preference one that does not involve JarJar Binx.

But ultimately, I must disagree with your proposal. I think we are well within rights, and perhaps duty, to warn a querent that they really don't need to go down the road they're going. Especially when they say they're writing a story and they just have to explain this macguffin. I think we'd be within rights to close as a matter of narrative necessity in those cases.

But there are other cases, where clearly the worldbuilder doesn't need to explain something, but is also not in danger of ruining a story either. I think that in these cases, we might actually be doing more harm than good in closing such questions. Some of us just build worlds to build worlds. We revel in the subcreative act and have the desire to learn everything we can about the other world. In my experience, we --- WB.SE --- are (currently) the single best place to explore these kinds of deeper worldbuilding questions.

Interesting last paragraph. The way I envision this working would be that there is either a very popular frame challenge stating as such or discussion in the comments where the community census is that explaining would not benefit the world building. As closure reasons go, I think it would perhaps be most open to challenge, but I envision that it would be used as a result of a consensus in the community.

The problem is not "Cool"-ness. It is brainstorming.
Let me first be clear, I do not like over-explaining things in fiction. Well, there is a place for explanations and there is not. But this is orthogonal.
The real issue is that such questions do not seek to explain. They are brainstorming writing prompts.
I like the Force example. Here is another aside before I continue: Many felt it lost a bit of its metaphorical magic when it was revealed that the Force is based on microorganisms. I did not like the way it was used. But I do find that "microorganisms cause magic" is a fascinating worldbuilding tool that is exceptionally powerful. What most frustrates me is that it was not even used to almost any effect. I want to get this out of the way before continuing because...it is contentious. And have seen arguments on both sides of whether it was a good decision or not.
Yet, again, the explanation to the Force is orthogonal. Let us look at how a Worldbuilding.SE question would look like:

In my universe, there is a thing called "the Force". Some people are able to manipulate it which allows for supernatural feats, like pushing or pulling items. Exerting other types of pressure or control, like chocking an opponent from afar. Some Force users can even produce lightning from their fingertips that strikes their opponents. Others can exist after death as sort of "ghost" - a remnant from their former self that can still carry the knowledge they have in life.
However, how do I explain how "the Force" works?

Reading this and knowing nothing about Star Wars, would you reach the conclusion that it was related microorganisms? No, not necessarily. It is certainly one possible answer, but other ones might be:

it is tied to the gods
the Force is a result of movements of the heavenly bodies
Force users have learned to manipulate physics at an instinctual level. Move atoms around to produce kinetic force or lightning
or even: the practitioners open tiny portals to elsewhere an can transfer "forces":

A force push is transferring kinetic energy from elsewhere to apply to your target
A force lightning is opening a portal to a stormy planet and letting a real lightning bolt seep through it



These are valid answers. Or rather, these are all valid responses to a writing prompt.
Of course worldbuilding is not rigid. You do exercise creativity when you introduce some elements. There are different levels of explanation that different works use. Isaac Asimov famously is into very hard science. Douglas Adamas, famously, not. And many authors and works fall within a spectrum of hardness (explanation) vs softness (I-said-so-ness).
What we look for here on the site should not be "what are all possible ways to explain this, even if no two are even alike". We are looking for consistency. The entire point to the site is that users should be able to find an answer to their query, if it was asked before. Questions are expected to have one canonical answer. Yes, multiple people are allowed to write answers but they should be in the same ballpark. While "microorganisms" and "tiny portals" are not.
Therefore, I do not think "Rule of Cool" is a good close reason. First of all, it does not really apply. We are not here to shut down questions as "you should not bother". Second, we already have "Needs details or clarity", "Needs more focus", "Opinion-based", "Not about worldbuilding", and "Too story based" as different reasons that might apply to questions that would fall under "Rule of cool". The different existing close reasons might match more or less depending on the content of the question. The example one about the Force, I would probably lean towards "Opinion-based". But there is always the custom close reason if no existing one strongly matches with why a question is off-topic.

I omitted a part about bottom-up vs top-down approaches. The "rule of cool" type of thing is a failure in top-down. I figured it is not really appropriate to discuss these when the topic is a new close reason. But perhaps we really should examine these in a meta (or even main?) post and offer practical advice what to do in each case to get around a road block. And how to make a question more on-topic.

First, all questions are, by definition, brainstorming questions. "What do you think 2+2 is?" is brainstorming if no one in the audience understands arithmatic. What maks a brainstorming question such is the open-ended "every answer has equal value" problem. Knowing this, I've left comments to the effect of, "this is a great idea and you shouldn't muddy the waters by adding to it" to questions that weren't brainstorming questions. They wouldn't have been closed for other reasons and I don't believe RoC questions can be identified that way. As usual, it's not that simple.

@JBH would you prefer a term more like "writing prompt questions"? Because not all questions are that. I thought I demonstrated what I mean with the example Force question. I don't think it closable because "rule of cool". I can change the term, if you prefer.

It's not the term, it's the idea that all questions that could or should be closed as RoC would always be closable for other reasons as well. I disagree with that and apologize that I wasn't clear.

I didn't say they always apply. I said we have existing close reasons that might apply. Yes, not all of them, not all the time, but the Force example is opinion-based for me. From my observations, maybe 80% of the time a "rule of cool" question (which is only really defined as "don't ask for this, we shouldn't answer it") would fall under one or more existing close reasons. And custom ones still exist. I don't think the RoC proposal, as it stands, is really good. It's just a random "this question gives me bad vibes" as described. There is no objective measure why it's off-topic.

@VLAZ - I see your point, that in most cases there is sufficient overlap with other closure reasons that it is not needed as its own option.

As much as I strongly encourage worldbuilders to be minimalist with what they explain, whether a story benefits from or is hindered by additional worldbuilding isn't a function of the world,. It's a function of how the story is written. You could have two stories with the same plot touching on the exact same aspects of the world and by virtue of the writing alone the sweet spot for what to include, and leave unsaid will be different.
Without closing questions we should still try to discourage people chasing extraneous details. Nobody cares that Gundam have too high a ground pressure to be practical. I see a big mech and I'm happy. A multi paragraph aside attempting to explain how this worlds mecha are actually physically plausible misses the point, and kills my willing suspension of disbelief. The time spent creating that explanation is better used asking is this relevant to what I intend to do with my world. Too much explanation shrinks and flattens the world, turning the fantastic into the mundane. Trust your readers to believe you when you say "this is how it is in my world", if they don't take you at your word no amount of explanation will change their mind.
